# Azure DevOps Rest API (Repository Contributors)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am looking for an Azure DevOps API to provide me with information on recent contributors to a specific repository. Is there a path that I can reach out to person names or git user information at least through the commits or PRs to a specific repository? Or Azure DevOps is not providing that at all?

What I'm looking for with an example from Github - https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/repos#list-repository-contributors

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there's no specific endpoint like that you pointed out. However, you can try to dig out the information you need:

- use [Get Pull Requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-requests/get-pull-requests?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) endpoint in order to get the top number of the most recent pull requests. Use `$top` and `$skip` input parameters to get the required set
- you'll get a collection of [GitPullRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-requests/get-pull-requests?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#gitpullrequest) objects, each containing the information you need:

  - createdBy: The identity of the user who created the pull request
  - closedBy: The user who closed the pull request
  - reviewers: A list of reviewers on the pull request along with the state of their votes

It should probably be enough for you to compile a list of the most recent contributors.